# Update ons-list on updating the array

Tags: onsen-ui

I am binding an array to ons-list. On updating the arraylist , the ons-list has to be updated. Is there any option like two way binding ?

I have tried $scope.$watch, but returned "undefined"

Comment: How is your ons-list built? using angularjs? share some code and maybe we could see the issue? or how to make it work with your code.

Comment: scope.$apply() to refresh the list....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you're using angular, here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<ons-list id="content" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ons-list-header>Persons</ons-list-header>
        <ons-list-item ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.name}}</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
<ons-button onclick="addNewPerson()">Click to Add a Person</ons-button>
```

**JS**

```
ons.bootstrap();
var theList = [{name: "John", age: 46},{name: "Debbie", age: 26}, {name: "Leslie", age: 35}];

function MyCtrl($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.persons = theList;
}

function addNewPerson() {
  var newPerson = {name: "Larry", age: 16};
  theList.push(newPerson);
  //alert(theList.length);
  //alert(document.getElementById("content"));
  var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("content")).scope();
  scope.persons = theList;
  myNavigator.resetToPage("myPage");
}
```

See it live here: 'http://codepen.io/vnguyen972/pen/eLlzh'

Comment: Thanks for reply. Using Angular.found the solution. used scope.$apply() to update the list alone. Previously tried "myNavigator.resetToPage("myPage");", but was refreshing the whole page. So used "scope.$apply()"